# How to limit Regex length based on its most outer capturing group and not on any special character set

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to implement regex for hostname with length range 1-5

But my regex is accepting any string with infinite lengths

This particular regex could not be done by quantifying individual character groups since my requirement is on the total size of hostname

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*([\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,4}$
```

The regex should be able to discard any character group with length greater than 5

Comment: It is accepting any length because of the nested quantifiers (`+` inside parentheses, these followed by `*`), see [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4jASiJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

In your regex the underlined part basically (greedy) matches as many "labels" with periods in between as possible.

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*([\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,4}$
 ----------------------------------------------------
```

#### A solution

```
^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)(?:\.(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)){0,4}$
```

Utilizing negative lookaheads and lookbehinds to verify the absence of '-' at the start and end.

I'm not quite shure if this is what you wanted but to explain
this regex matches:

1. at least one label at max 5 labels
2. each label consists of at least one character (alphanumeric or '-') and at max 63 chars
3. a label has no '-' as first or last char
4. each label is separated by a period

---

> This particular regex could not be done by quantifying individual character groups since my requirement is on the total size of hostname

If you want to limit the size of the match, you can add an something like

```
(?=^.{1,20}$)
```

to the beginning of the regex. This ensures that the string has at max 20 characters.

Comment: My requirement is to limit the maximum size of my complete regex but I am not able to do it with ^(?=^\.{1,20}$)(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*([\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*)*[a-zA-Z0-9])$ either. Please check and suggest further.

Comment: @Arun maybe i misunderstood your intention. Could you provide a few examples of strings that get accepted and some that don't.

Comment: @Arun i found a mistake: the prefix should be `(?=^.{1,20}$)` (without the '\').